# Associations with FactoryBot in Rails: Validation Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following in my locations factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :location do
   name 'MyString'
   hours_operation 'MyString'
   abbreviation 'MyString'
   address_1 'MyString'
   address_2 'MyString'
   city 'MyString'
   state 'MyString'
   postal_code 1
   phone 'MyString'
   fax 'MyString'
   association :region
 end
end
```

I have the following in my regions factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :region do
    name 'MyString'
   end
 end
```

Region has_many locations and Locations belongs_to region.

However in my testing I keep getting Validation failed: Region must exist.

I have tried the following:

```
after(:create) do |location, _evaluator|
 create_list(:region, evaluator.region, location: location)
end

association :region, factory: region

before(:create) do |region|
  region.location << FactoryBot.build(:location, region: region)
end
```

I've also tried in regions factory:

```
factory :region_with_location do
  after(:create) do |region|
   create(:location, region: region)
   end
end
```

In locations factory:

```
association :region, factory: :region_with_location
```

In each case I still keep getting: Validation failed: Region must exist.

Comment: I think it's because you're calling << in before(:create), where a region is not yet saved. Can you try to change that?

Comment: Also belongs_to association changed its default behaviour with rails 5. you can change that with `optional: true` parameter in the belongs_to call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Location` belongs_to `Region`, an instance of Region must be created in the test database before building **and** saving a Location. This is why your code doesn't work here, as @Niklas says:

```
after(:create) do |location, _evaluator|
 create_list(:region, evaluator.region, location: location)
end
```

What you could do is the reverse: Build a list of locations via association after a region is created.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :region do
    name 'MyString'

  factory :region_with_locations do
    transient do
      locations_count 5
    end

    after(:create) do |region, evaluator|
      create_list(:location, evaluator.locations_count, region: region)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also look into using a [`before(:create)` callback](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) to create a region before assigning it to a location.